# distribute a number of zeros anywhere in a grid

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have a square 2dvector (grid) and I want to insert into it a number ("conc") of zeros.
And then ,shuffle the vector in order to distribute the zeros.
(let's say grid vector is size 10x10).

1) I tried :

```
       int conc=1;

        for (size_t i=0, max=conc; i!=max;i++){
                grid.erase(grid.begin()+1);

            for (size_t j=0,max=grid.size();j!=max; j++)
                grid[i][j]=0;
            }


            random_shuffle(grid.begin(),grid.end());
```

The problem is that with the above I  am receiving 10 zeros (grid size=10x10) instead 1 (right now conc=1,so I want 1 zero).

And these ten zeros are all in one row.I want to distribute the number of zeros anywhere in the grid.

I want to insert 1 zero (conc).

Comment: You might want to read a [`std::random_shuffle` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle).

Comment: `std::random_shuffle` returns nothing

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg:I checked it but in 2d vector I didn't manage to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array like this:

```
arr[LINES*COLUMNS]
```

and instead of

```
arr[i][j]
```

access it as

```
arr[i*COLUMNS+j]
```

Using this approach everything is linear, assuming you want this behavior for your shuffling...

**UPDATE**

amd as Joachim Pileborg suggested... read more about the random_shufle...

Answer (score 0):

```
//is this what you intended
int conc=10;
 for (size_t i=0, max=grid.size(); i!=max;i++){
            for (size_t j=0,max=grid.size();j!=max; j++)
                grid[i][j]=conc;//change here
            }
```

Comment: :I want to fill the array with "conc" zeros.For example with 10 zeros.

Comment: @George what do you mean by ten zeros ? Do you mean it must have exactly ten zeros anywhere in matrix `grid` ?

Comment: @George  it seemed you were filling the entire array structure with value zero before.  Are you already Successful there?  Is there some other value other than  zero you care that is part of your requirements?   You probably want to do something that will be easy.  We just need to understand what you need.

Comment: @user3003631:I am creating a 2d vector which contain ones (1).I want to insert into it a number of zeros (conc).Then,I want to shuffle it in order for the zeros to distributed inside the vector.I updated,please check.Also , thanks for the other answer ,but I want to do it in the way I have it.Thank you.

Comment: @user3003631:I hope you understand my problem.I think I am close.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[`std::random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) returns nothing

You should just display the matrix after using the algorithm

```
random_shuffle(&arr[0][0], &arr[0][0] + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0][0])); 

for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
 for(std::size_t j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
   std::cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
 std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: :Hmm,it runs but shuffle doesn't worl as expected.I want to return one element from arr,but it may return for example "1 1" which doesn't exist in arr!Also,by 10 zeros I mean ,I want to add to grid 10 zeros and then shuffle the vector.

Comment: :Ok, as for the shuffle ,the mistake was using  arr[0][0] , we must use arr[0].As for my other questions if you can help .I appreciate it.Thanks

Comment: How ten zeros to `grid`, is it a 5x2 matrix ? Re-phrase your problem statement, looks like you have a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/232397)

Comment: @POW:grid has dimensions "plex,plex" , where plex an int.I want to insert some number of zeros ("conc") in it.I know how to do it in 1d vector,but not in 2d.Then , after inserting a number of zeros , I want to shuffle it.

Comment: @George, then use a counter as `conc`, add zeros at first `conc` places of `grid` till `--conc != 0`, break the loop, now shuffle this `grid`, make sure you fill grid with some other numbers before filling it with `conc` zeros, otherwise it will have garbage values

Comment: @POW:I updated my anser and added what you suggested but because I am not familiar with vectors it doesn't work as intented.Also,if you know about my 3 question.Thanks!

Comment: @POW:I updated my answer.If you can help..Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
//I do not want to violate your constraints and
//if you are willing to encapsulate something
//we can let the compiler deal with size observations about an old fashioned array
struct pairx
{
    int d[2];
};

int a_test_200()
{
pairx x{{4,3}};//notice more braces ..used only for explanation to human
//also consider std::vector if your constraints permit
pairx arrp[]={  { {0,1}},{  {1,0}}, { {0,-1}}, { {-1,0} } };
cout << "original" << endl;
for (const auto & e : arrp) cout << e.d[0] << " " <<  e.d[1] << ", ";
cout << endl;
//we assume you shuffle opaque structure pairx
random_shuffle(begin(arrp), end(arrp));
cout << "shuffle" << endl;
for (const auto & e : arrp) cout << e.d[0] << " " <<  e.d[1] << ", ";
cout << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @George This encapsulated approach may preserve your notion of the data ... here written as pairx.  This is in reference to your comment below about shuffling more than you intended.